# jQuery AJAX URL path issue

Tags: php, jquery

In jQuery AJAX url place, if I give `http://172.121.0.1/filename.php`, it's working. If I give `http://localhost/filename.php` then it's working. Please help me.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://172.22.0.155/login/login_check",
          type: "POST",
          data:$("#logins").serialize(),
          beforeSend: function(){
            $("#err").html("");
          },
          success: function($msg){
             if($msg=="yes"){
                document.location.href=urls+"main/";
             }else{
               $("#err").html("Please enter correct username and password");
               return false;
             }
          },error:function (msg){
           alert(msg);
          }
        });
```

Comment: It's working either way? That doesn't sound so bad.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "it's **not** working", but for which? It's probably a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) conflict.

Comment: Also, your browser most likely has an error console. I recommend you look in there for clues

Comment: If i am giving with ip address its not working. If i am giving localhost then its working fine

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly your iis settings issue and not jquery ajax problem. Try " http://172.121.0.1/filename.php" in the browser directly see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems define localhost as 127.0.0.1

Try that IP and see it is works.

Also, if you're hitting the same server that your sending this call from, you don't need the domain/IP.

If you are hitting a different server than you have a CORS issue.